# C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm using this codeproject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4682/Voice-chat-using-a-client-server-architecture

```
class mysocket : public CSocket  
{
public:
    CDialog *dlg;
    CString name;
    int closeflag;

    mysocket();
    setparent(CDialog *dlg);
    //void OnConnect(int errcode);
    void OnReceive(int errcode);
    void OnClose(int errcode);


};
```

But I get this error in numerous places:

```
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I think it has something to do with me using the latest version of visual studio (2013).

Comment: You have no return type for `setparent(CDialog *dlg);`

Comment: @NathanOliver: `mysocket()` is a constructor and shouldn't have return type.

Comment: @myaut thanks for catching that.  I'm used to classes starting with a capital so i thought it was just a function.

Comment: The linked CodeProject article was written back in 2003 (and it probably was compilable with the VS version available at that time). Visual Studio evolved since then. C++ itself had one or two revisions in the meantime. Omitting the return type (assuming int) was not a good practice even back in 2003. Just add the missing `int` return type and go on.